# Javascript + PHP AJAX: Record Audio and Upload failing with 'success'

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to capture a recorded message and then upload it to a directory. For some reason the response of the AJAX is logging `success` but it is not actually doing anything.

I'm not sure how to upload zip files here so I can just post the whole code.

I also apologise if this is noobie, I am a just starting out junior developer.

index.html Page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test audio ajax</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="center-align">

<audio controls="" id="audio" src="#"></audio>
<br/>>
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" id="startRecording">Start</button>
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" id="stopRecording" disabled="true">Stop and upload</button>
<br/>>
<a id="download" class="" href="#" download="AudioTest.wav">Download Audio</a>

</div>

<hr>
<div class="hiddendiv common"></div></body>
</body>
</html>
```

in that html page I have this javascript:

```
<script>
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

let getBrowser = () => {
    //console.log('function getBrowser() {');
    var nVer = navigator.appVersion;
    var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;
    var browserName  = navigator.appName;
    var fullVersion  = ''+parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
    var majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion,10);
    var nameOffset,verOffset,ix;

    // In Opera, the true version is after "Opera" or after "Version"
    if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Opera"))!=-1) {
    browserName = "Opera";
    fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+6);
    if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Version"))!=-1)
        fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
    }
    // In MSIE, the true version is after "MSIE" in userAgent
    else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("MSIE"))!=-1) {
    browserName = "Microsoft Internet Explorer";
    fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+5);
    }
    // In Chrome, the true version is after "Chrome"
    else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Chrome"))!=-1) {
    browserName = "Chrome";
    fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+7);
    }
    // In Safari, the true version is after "Safari" or after "Version"
    else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Safari"))!=-1) {
    browserName = "Safari";
    fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+7);
    if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Version"))!=-1)
        fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
    }
    // In Firefox, the true version is after "Firefox"
    else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Firefox"))!=-1) {
    browserName = "Firefox";
    fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
    }
    // In most other browsers, "name/version" is at the end of userAgent
    else if ( (nameOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf(' ')+1) < (verOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf('/')) ) {
    browserName = nAgt.substring(nameOffset,verOffset);
    fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+1);
    if (browserName.toLowerCase()==browserName.toUpperCase()) {
    browserName = navigator.appName;
    }
    }
    // trim the fullVersion string at semicolon/space if present
    if ((ix=fullVersion.indexOf(";"))!=-1)
    fullVersion=fullVersion.substring(0,ix);
    if ((ix=fullVersion.indexOf(" "))!=-1)
    fullVersion=fullVersion.substring(0,ix);

    majorVersion = parseInt(''+fullVersion,10);
    if (isNaN(majorVersion)) {
    fullVersion  = ''+parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
    majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion,10);
    }

    return browserName;
}

if (typeof MediaRecorder === 'undefined' || !navigator.getUserMedia) {
    alert('MediaRecorder not supported on your browser, use Firefox 30 or Chrome 49 instead.');
}

if (getBrowser() == "Chrome") {
    //console.log('if Chrome');
    var constraints = {"audio": true, "video": {  "mandatory": {  "minWidth": 640,  "maxWidth": 640, "minHeight": 480,"maxHeight": 480 }, "optional": [] } }; //Chrome
} else if (getBrowser() == "Firefox") {
    //console.log('else Firefox');
    var constraints = {audio: true, video: { width: { min: 640, ideal: 640, max: 640 },  height: { min: 480, ideal: 480, max: 480 } } }; //Firefox
} else {
    //console.log('else Chrome');
    var constraints = {"audio": true, "video": false };//Chrome
}

let pre = document.querySelector('pre');
let shouldStop;
let stopped;
let mediaRecorder;
let audio = document.querySelector('audio');
let downloadLink = document.getElementById('download');
let startBtn = document.getElementById('startRecording');
let stopBtn = document.getElementById('stopRecording');
let codeBtn = document.querySelector('.js-code');

let handleSuccess = (stream) => {
    let options;
    let recordedChunks = [];
    shouldStop = false;
    stopped = false;

    if (typeof MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported == 'function'){
    if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('audio/webm;codecs=opus')) {
        options = {mimeType: 'audio/webm;codecs=opus'};
    } else if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('audio/ogg;codecs=opus')) {
        options = {mimeType: 'audio/ogg;codecs=opus'};
    }
    //console.log('mimeType: '+options.mimeType);
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
    } else {
    //console.log('mimeType DEFAULT');
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    }

    startBtn.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    stopBtn.removeAttribute('disabled');
    mediaRecorder.start(10);

    mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', function(e) {
    if (e.data.size > 0) {
        recordedChunks.push(e.data);
        //console.log(e.data);
    }

    if(shouldStop === true && stopped === false) {
        //console.log('Stop');
        stopBtn.setAttribute('disabled', true);
        startBtn.removeAttribute('disabled');
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        stream.getAudioTracks().forEach(function (track) {
        track.stop();
        });
        stopped = true;
    }
    });

    mediaRecorder.addEventListener('start', function(e) {
    //console.log('Started, state = ' + mediaRecorder.state);
    });

    mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', function() {
    audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(recordedChunks));
    downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(recordedChunks));
    downloadLink.download = 'file' + Date.now() + '.wav';
    downloadLink.classList.remove('hide');
    //$('#ibenic_file_input').val(downloadLink.download)
    var form_data = new FormData();                  
    form_data.append('file', audio.src);
    uploadFile(form_data);

    });




    mediaRecorder.addEventListener('warning', function(e) {
    log('Warning: ' + e);
    });

    mediaRecorder.addEventListener('error', evt => {
    //console.log(evt);
    reject(evt);
    });
};

let errorCallback = (error) => {
    alert(error);
    //console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error); 
};

startBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navigator.getUserMedia({"audio": true, "video": false}, handleSuccess, errorCallback);
});

stopBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    shouldStop = true;
});  

</script>
```

I also have this script on the same page under that:

```
<script>
function uploadFile(form_data) {                            
    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php', // point to server-side PHP script 
        dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,                         
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data){
            console.log('success: ' + data);
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

and finally I have an upload.php file which contains:

```
if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
}
else {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
}
```

I created the folder `uploads` and have set the chmod to 777.

Apart from that I am a little lost on what to do and check. Please could someone help me how to get that generated audio file passed to the ajax request and uploaded?

As a junior developer it would be greatly appreciated if the code was commented or links to references as I don't want to become a copy and paster and would like to learn.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `777` is not such a good idea. especially for uploaded files!

Comment: try to echo the return of `move_uploaded_file` to see what you've got there. also do a `var_dump($_FILES)` at the beginning to check if you receive anything at all.

Comment: Thanks trying that now. Only did 777 for test.

Comment: @Jeff I get: PHP Notice: Undefined index: file in public_html/ajax/upload.php on line 10 which is the move_uploaded_file()

Comment: now check `var_dump($_FILES);`

Comment: @Jeff retunrs: "NULL↵{"result":null}"

Comment: @jeff btw, I just want to say I appreciate you helping me with this.

Comment: ok, `$_FILES` is not defined -> ajax is not sending any files. So this `form_data.append('file', audio.src);` seems to be failing. Most likely `audio.src` is failing. You'd have to continue debugging from there on...

Comment: @Jeff This is where I am getting stuck. I have passed almost every variable I can think of that is defined in that code. My issue is getting the form data for the file. Any ideas? Anyone ?